# How to make this fraction addition operator work?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fractions

```
  Fraction &operator+= (const Fraction &obj){
    if (denom == obj.denom){
      num += obj.num;
    }
    else{   
      lcm = l_c_m(num, denom);
      num * (lcm / denom) += obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);
    }
    return *this;  //returns current object
  }

//calculating highest common denominator
int g_c_d(int n, int d){
    return d == 0? n : g_c_d(d, n % d);
 }

int l_c_m(int a, int b){
  int temp = g_c_d(a, b);
  return temp ? (a / (temp * b)) : 0;
    }

int main(){
   cout << frac1 << " +  " << frac2 << " = ";
   cout << (frac1 += frac2) << endl;
   }
```

I am trying to add fractions using this code. Hoever the overloaded addition operator doesnt work when the denominators are different. But the code does work when the denominators are the same.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful description.

Comment: `num * (lcm / denom) += obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your function should look something like

```
Fraction &operator+= (const Fraction &obj){
    if (denom == obj.denom){
        num += obj.num;
    } else {
        num = num * obj.denom + obj.num * denom;
        denom *= obj.denom;
    }
    normalize(); // simplify num and obj
    return *this;  //returns current object
}
```

Comment: Your one partially worked. I had to use my g_c_d() function to simplify tho. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is the purpose of `normalize()` or whatever you name this function in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to do: `lcm = lcm(obj.denom, denom);`

Then you need to change this line: `num * (lcm / denom) += obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);`

To this: `num  = num * (lcm / denom) + obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);`

Incidentally you'll also need to update your `denom`. `denom = lcm;`

Comment: Chance are that OP wants `(num * lcm) / denom` over `num * (lcm / denom)`

Comment: @Jarod42 What I assumed that he meant to do `lcm = lcm(obj.denom, denom);` Maybe that isn't the case? There are some problems with this code...

Answer (score 1):

lcm = l_c_m(obj.denom, denom);
num = num * (lcm / denom) + obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);

Answer (score 0):

You seriously mean this ?  :-O

```
num * (lcm / denom) += obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);
```

do it right :-

```
num = num * (lcm / denom) + obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);
```

Comment: I was working on it so late I dont even know what i was writing. In a team project we're a man short and the other guy hasn't even conrtibuted much; so when stressed mistakes happen

Comment: that happens a lot with me too, as i did earlier above till jonathan pointed it out  :-P

Comment: Yeah man my team mate isn't even communicating properly doing my head in

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code should be like this

```
Fraction &operator+= (const Fraction &obj){
if (denom == obj.denom){
  num += obj.num;
}
else{   
  lcm = l_c_m(obj.denom, denom);
 num= num * (lcm / denom) + obj.num * (lcm / obj.denom);
}
return *this;  //returns current object
```

}

Comment: It is helpful to at least give a short explanation of your answer as opposed to just dropping in code.